# How to calculate average height of a binary tree?

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-tree

Average height of a binary tree is equal to the sum of the height of each nodes divided by the total nodes.

However, how do you calculate the sum of the height of each nodes? Do we have to include the leave nodes as well? And, is the height of leave node = 1?

Thorough explanation with examples would be great!

For instance, with the binary tree shown below:

```
       1
   2       9
0   3    4   10
```

The ans should be 1.4285
Starting from the leave nodes, I get a total of:
1+1+1+1+2+2+3 = 11

So the avg height I get is = 11/7 which is not equal to 1.4285.
What have I done wrong here?

Comment: This is a good journal describing and explaining the average height of binary trees and other simple trees. Authors: Philippe Flajolet and Andrew Odlyzko.

http://ac.els-cdn.com/0022000082900046/1-s2.0-0022000082900046-main.pdf?_tid=9871c284-0db0-11e5-bcbd-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1433748962_7e404f06e9ccee7e96fbcf35de5217bb

Hope this helps!

Comment: Height == distance from root node.

Comment: I think I get it! Height = the distance from root node, so from the first (very left node), the height = 2. Hence, 2+2+2+2+1+1 = 10!

Comment: @Qbb That's right. So it's 10/7 = 1.4285

Answer (score 1):

You have already figured it out but for further references here is some code to calculate the average height in `c#`, which uses recursion:

```
namespace AverageHeight
{
    public class tree
    {
        public tree left;
        public tree right;
    }

    class Program
    {
        static int count = 1;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var tree = new tree()
            {
                left = new tree() { left = new tree(), right = new tree() },
                right = new tree() { left = new tree(), right = new tree() }
            };

            var avg = (decimal)Height(tree, 0) / count;
        }

        static int Height(tree t, int l)
        {
            if (t.left != null) count++;
            if (t.right != null) count++;

            return l + (t.left != null ? Height(t.left, l + 1) : 0) +
                       (t.right != null ? Height(t.right, l + 1) : 0);
        }
    }
}
```